# Open source and secure app to replace Google Keep

Tags: software-recommendation, notes

As part of moving away from Google products I'm looking to replace Google Keep. I would love an installable client for Ubuntu but that's optional. I do need an Android app and access via browser. Should have a privacy focus and preferably be open source. I'm currently trying out Standard Notes but it lacks functionality such as uploading images and lists with checkbockes.

Comment: What does "Google Keep" do for you? What functionality do you seek?

Comment: Check boxes for lists and uploading pictures.

Answer (score 1):

[QOwnNotes](http://www.qownnotes.org/) seems to become a good replacement. May be self-hosted. Supports Markdown.

Comment: Looks good but running my own Nextcloud server is a bit above my head :(